# Why need $T$ be onto?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(E,||\cdot||_1)$ be a normed linear space and let $F$ be the space of all continuous linear transformations from $\mathbb R$ to $E$.

Consider $T: E \to F$, $x \mapsto Tx: \mathbb R \to E$, $t \mapsto Tx(t) = tx$

Then, why is $T$ onto?

Comment: well this says a linear transformation from R to E is determined by where 1 goes.  do you believe that?

Comment: Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{R} \to E$, find some $x_0$ such that $T x_0 = \phi$. Note that $(T x_0)(1) = x_0 = \phi(1)$.

Comment: Please don't delete questions right after they received an answer. That's unfair to the answerer whose effort then is doomed to remain unrewarded.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f \in F$.  Then $f : \mathbb R \to E$ is linear, so that $f(t) = t f(1)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

Let $f \in F$ and let $x \in E$ be given by $x = f(1)$. Then $Tx(t) = tx = tf(1) = f(t)$.

Thus $Tx(t) = f(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$, meaning $Tx = f$. Thus $T$ is onto.